# Can't customize TKInter button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I want to make the **bg** of the button **'#318CE7'** this hex color, but no matter what I tried, the color did not change and when the application ran, the color of the button became white.

```
bg_color = (49, 140, 231)
bg_hex = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*bg_color)

start_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Start", bg=bg_hex, fg="white", font=("Arial", 16), bd=0, relief=tk.RIDGE, command=start_app)
```

[image]

I tried solving the problem with **ChatGPT** but the button did **not turn blue**.

I'm using **macOS Big Sur**

Comment: It works in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.16. However what is the point of setting `relief` option when `bd=0`?

Comment: @acw1668 ChatGPT created this code for me, I'm not very familiar with tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue for tkinter and mac sadly. I have run into similar things when i was using tkinter for a small app. The solution to this is to install the dedicated mac library. A sample code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import Button
    
bg_color = (0x31, 0x8C, 0xE7)
bg_hex = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*bg_color)

start_btn = Button(root, text="Start", bg=bg_hex, fg="white", font=("Arial", 16), bd=0, relief=tk.RIDGE, command=start_app)
```

As you can see we are using the Button from the `tkmacosx` package, that will solve your issue and make the button blue.

Just install the `tkmacosx` before you run this with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello world")
window.geometry("300x300")

bg_color = (0x31, 0x8C, 0xE7)
bg_hex = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*bg_color)

start_btn = tk.Button(window, text="Start", bg=bg_hex, fg="white", font=("Arial", 16), bd=0, relief=tk.RIDGE)
start_btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I tested it in repl.it and it worked.

Comment: It didn't work on macOS, the output is still the same